# Where is the Vilna Gaon's story of revealing his tefillin shel rosh in court?

Tags: tefilin, vilna-gaon

[Many](https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=378) [people](https://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=118&style=print) [quote](https://www.bircas.org/bo-6/) a story of the Vilna Gaon revealing his tefillin shel rosh when facing ridiculous charges in court. Where is the oldest known source for this story?

Comment: An extremely similar story is also told about the Baal ha-Tanya... one wonders whether their  identities in the story were swapped at some point.